# unable to set service user account via command line

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, command-line-interface, windows-service, wmi

I am writing a puppet script to automate creation of TeamCity agents on Windows 2008 R2 SP2.
For this, I need to set a custom TeamCity service user account via command-line.

So far, I have tried this sequence of commands:

**1) Grant my custom account "log on as a service right":**

> ntrights +r SeServiceLogonRight -u teamcity@omnicorp

Windows confirms command worked successfully:

> Granting SeServiceLogonRight to teamcity@omnicorp   ... successful

**2) Set service user account:**

> (Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "name='TCBuildAgent'").Change($Null,$Null,$Null,$Null,$Null,$Null,'teamcity@omnicorp','password')

...command fails with error 21:

> __GENUS          : 2
>   __CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
>   __SUPERCLASS     :
>   __DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
>   __RELPATH        :
>   __PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
>   __DERIVATION     : {}
>   __SERVER         :
>   __NAMESPACE      :
>   __PATH           :
>   ReturnValue      : **21**
>   PSComputerName   :

Here's what I know so far:

- [Error 21 translates to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384901(v=vs.85).aspx) "Invalid parameters have been passed to the service."
- Username/password are valid - I know this because I am able to make this change via the services.msc snap-in
- Whenever I apply custom user manually, the above commands start to work (I have tested this on numerous fresh VMs).
- This tells me `ntrights` alone is not enough to allow domain account to be used a service user.

This is where I am stuck. All evidence suggests `ntrights` is sufficient, but something is still missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "name='TCBuildAgent'").Change($Null,$Null,$Null,$Null,$Null,$False,'teamcity@omnicorp','password')
```

The 6th parameter correspond to "DesktopInteract", and normally, the service cannot be granted rights to interact with the desktop, unless it is the Local System account.